# GWT Internationalization Tool

Tags: gwt, internationalization

Is there a tool for creating / editing the properties-Files (and [optional] the interfaces) for the GWT internationalization (i18n) with Constants and Messages?

Comment: I also found i18nCreator, but I'm searching for a more automated solution as well, that's why I stared the bounty. Is there a tool, that will find all Strings in the project and externalize them to the .property file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have found a way to externalize all strings in a project:

Instantiations was [bought up by Google, which released their tools](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2010/09/google-relaunches-instantiations.html) (for example the GWT Designer) at no charge. The **[GWT Designer](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/tools/download-gwtdesigner.html)** is able to externalize specific or all strings and there are other great [internationalization features](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/features/gwt/internationalization.html).

You can for example, check the translated dialogs for a language in the design view.

Answer (score 1):

@JochenJung: You might wanna check out [this script](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/MergeLocale). It provides some support for collecting all messages found in the ui.xml files. It's not exactly brilliant but at least a step in the right direction.